# angular печать страницы

Tags: angular

как распечатать html таблицу из ангуляра со всеми стилями?
пробовал пару скриптов, не подхватываются стили, в скрипте путь указывать к css пробовал, не помогло
upd: табличные тэги так же не берутся в страницу печати, через код элемента их нет, одни лишь спаны, ссылки, без табличной обертки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее может кому пригодится:

Ссылаться в скрипте нужно на элемент выше того что печатать надо
т.е. в моем случае мне нужно было отправить на печать `<table>` и я ссылался на тейбл.

А нужно было просто обернуть дивом и перенести `<table>` и все что внутри него в див и потом уже ссылаться на див